# Optional AccountDBO value in safe unwrap not evaluating as true

Tags: swift, adobe, analytics

Working with **Adobe Analytics** in Swift 4 and iOS, trying to pass a *String* as the product for the Analytics; while doing a *safe unwrap* using an optional value as part of the condition, the code *if let* condition is not evaluating as expected(true) even though the optional value exist.

```
func setTransaction(date: Date) {

    /// Analytics for scheduled transfer
    if let product = self.getDestinationAccount()?.typeName {
      print("I TOLD U")
      self.transferAnalyticsHelper.trackScheduleDateTransfer(product: product)
    }
    self.transferAnalyticsHelper.trackScheduleDateTransfer(product: "Here IT WORKS!")

    captureModel.transactionDate = date.hummanDateFormat(format: "dd MMM yyyy' 'HH:mm:ss").capitalizeFirst
    getCaptureInterfaceInfo()

  }
```

Since the optional method is inside of a presenter and already in use in several other parts of the project, I'm finding a way to solve this issue and give the Analytics the product as expected.

Comment: If you don't see the `"I TOLD U"` print, then that means either `self.getDestinationAccount()` is returning `nil` or that isn't nil but `typeName` is `nil`.

Comment: Yes, not seeing `"I TOLD U"` so it's not going inside. Hadn't thought about the `typeName` situation though.

Comment: Right, and I just told you why.

Comment: Thank you! Now it works and it looks like this.
`func setTransaction(date: Date) {

    /// Analytics for scheduled transfer
    if let product = self.getDestinationAccount()?.typeName as String! {
      self.transferAnalyticsHelper.trackScheduleDateTransfer(product: product)
    }
`

_Two heads are better than one_ for sure.  **xoxo**

Comment: Get rid of the `!` after the `as String`. It makes no sense to cast the value to an implicitly unwrapped `String`.

Comment: Have to use it because of Swiftlint rules in the project. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Oh, and finally, please add your _comment/answer_ as an answer so I can check this as solved. Again, thanks a lot.

Comment: Then you need to fix your Swiftline rules. It's wrong. It makes no sense to use `as String!` with `if let`.

Comment: Actually, it's because `typeName: String?` not because of Swfitlint rules. Double-checked on that one.

Comment: You actually don't even need the `as String` then.

Comment: Well, without it, the _if let_ is not working as expected, i.e. evaluating as `False`. Because as you said, `typeName` was evaluating as `nil`

Comment: That's how it is supposed to work. If either `self.getDestinationAccount()` or `typeName` are `nil`, then the `if let` won't be entered.